# Why can't I validate values with the $ symbol in it?

Tags: asp.net

I am using a CompareValidator to check user input on one of my forms but for some reason it will not allow me to enter a dollar sign.

[According to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.comparevalidator.aspx) the currency data type in the compare validator allows:

> A decimal data type that can contain
>   currency symbols.

I am using the control below to validate:

```
<asp:CompareValidator ID="vld_Cash" runat="server" ControlToValidate="CashTextBox" Type="Currency" Operator="DataTypeCheck" ValidationGroup="vld_Update" ErrorMessage="The value entered for 'Cash' must be in a number format.  Do NOT include dollar signs.  Examples: 500 or 500.00" />
```

I also added the following to my web.config just to be sure:

```
<globalization culture="en-US" uiCulture="en-US"/>
```

But it still says any input with a $ in it is invalid.  Am I missing something here?

Comment: +1 good question. Not sure who downvoted this question, but I can confirm the same behaviour in a new webforms app in .NET 4

Comment: I searched Connect, and there are no defects filed against CompareValidator and currency. Perhaps file one yourself for mucho cred + respect? :)

Comment: Good idea, you can say you knew me before I was famous ;)  https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/595932/comparevalidator-does-not-allow-currency-to-have-the-symbol-in-it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last comment in this thread shows why and gives you some ideas:

[Currency Validator](http://forums.asp.net/t/1212378.aspx)

An article dedicated to this:

[ASP.Net: Validating a TextBox with a Dollar Sign](http://graciesdad.wordpress.com/2009/08/26/asp-net-validating-a-text-box-with-a-dollar-sign/) (suggests using a RegularExpressionValidator).

Comment: True, those are some workarounds, but the MSDN docs even say "A decimal data type that can contain currency symbols." Indeed. Either the docs or the implementation is wrong. Perhaps Connect has details...

Comment: MSDN docs sometimes contain bugs... :) It's MSDN bug or the underlying code of the Validator that is buggy.

Comment: How can @p.campbell's comment appears before mine? StackOverflow bug? @Abe Miessler had commented before but deleted his comment. Maybe this caused this behavior.

Comment: @Leniel: I've edited my comment twice. Never saw a comment from Abe here. Everything looks in order to me. (shrug)

Comment: Ahh... OK. Now I understand. I thought that Abe had made that first comment. @p.campbell modified his comment and I thought this was a new comment. :D

Comment: Just had to comment and say that this comment debate is worthless.